# Transpose the data in python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have dataset in this format.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj2pa.png)

And I want to convert into below format. Can someone please help me out by sharing the python code to convert the above format into below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvXCc.png)

Comment: You need to `pivot`

Comment: I tried but I'm unable to shape in that way. Can you help me out?

Comment: you need to provide a fully reproducible example